# Decode custom object using Jackson JsonDeserializer

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm new to Kotlin (coming from Swift) and I have a quite simple json that I need to decode into two different Kotlin class based a field of that json. If the field is `"type": "Square"` I want to decode an `Square` class, if the field is `"type": "Rectangle",`, I want to decode a `Rectangle` class.

The json I need to decode is either

```
{
  "type": "Square",
  "size": "1"
}
```

or

```
{
  "type": "Rectangle",
  "width": 1,
  "length": 2
}
```

And my .kt class is defined as so.  I wrote a custom `JsonDeserializer` but it does not seem to work as `jp.readValueAs(Square::class.java)` retuns null.

```kotlin
@JsonDeserialize(using = Shape.Deserializer::class)
sealed class Shape {
    enum class Type {
        Rectangle,
        Square
    }

    abstract val type: Type

    data class Square(
        val size: Int
    ) : Shape() {
        override val type: Type = Type.Square
    }

    data class Rectangle(
        val width: Int,
        val length: Int
    ) : Shape() {
        override val type: Type = Type.Rectangle
    }

    class Deserializer: JsonDeserializer<Shape>() {
        override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Shape {
            var node = jp.readValueAsTree<JsonNode>()
            return when(node.get("type").asText()) {
                Type.Square.name ->
                    jp.readValueAs(Square::class.java)
                Type.Rectangle.name ->
                    jp.readValueAs(Rectangle::class.java)
                else -> throw JsonMappingException("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what did I do wrong?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: I think it's possible to switch on the `type` property using annotations on my `Shape` class as follows

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Shape.Square::class, name = "Square"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Shape.Rectangle::class, name = "Rectangle")
    ]
)
sealed class Shape {
    enum class Type {
        Rectangle,
        Square
    }
    abstract val type: Type
    data class Square(
        val size: Int
    ) : Shape() {
        override val type: Type = Type.Square
    }

    data class Rectangle(
        val width: Int,
        val length: Int
    ) : Shape() {
        override val type: Type = Type.Rectangle
    }
}
```